# Array index is not accessable because it is Friend

Tags: arrays, vb.net, serial-port

I am getting and error when I bring my code into another project. In a blank project it works fine, I really have no idea how to get around it, here is the error

Error   1   'System.Data.Index' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

```
        Dim DataString As String = txtAdvancedCommand.Text
    ' Create an array containing from each letter in Textbox
    Dim charArray() As Char = DataString.ToCharArray

    For index = 0 To charArray.GetUpperBound(0)      <-----ERROR on word index
        Try
            'Now lets send the data
            If SerialPort.IsOpen Then
                SerialPort.Write(charArray(index) & vbCrLf)    <-----ERROR on word index
            Else
                ConnectSerial()
                SerialPort.Write(charArray(index) & vbCrLf)    <-----ERROR on word index
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            txtLog.AppendText(e.Message & vbCrLf)
        End Try
    Next
```

now the project I am bringing into has a DLL and I suspect it has something to do with it, I cannot get the source code to the DLL so is there another way around this?

Comment: Where is the `Dim index as Integer` statement?

Comment: The error message suggests that there's a `System.Data.Index` class, whose accessibility is `Friend`, that the compiler is confusing for your index variable. Does the error go away if you explicitly declare it? `For index As Integer = 0 To charArray.GetUpperBound(0)...`?

Comment: Thanks guys, I dont understand why It would not require to be declared as an int in another project. Thanks for everyones help, much appreciated.

Comment: @gray.rabbit - That's why it is important to always put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file or set it in the project properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
For index As Integer= 0 To charArray.GetUpperBound(0)
```

or better yet

```
For index As Integer= 0 To charArray.Length
```

or better yet

```
Dim DataString As String = txtAdvancedCommand.Text
' Create an array containing from each letter in Textbox
Dim charArray As String() = Array.ConvertAll(DataString.ToCharArray(), Function(c) c.ToString())
Dim output As String = String.Join(vbCrLf, charArray)
If Not SerialPort.IsOpen Then
    ConnectSerial()
End If
SerialPort.Write(output)
```